# UHF Phase Modulation

Tags: rf, communication, modulation, digital-communications, dds

I would like to design a system that produces -10 degrees and +10 degrees phase shifts at 409.6MHz (Basically BPSK).

The way I'm thinking about approaching this is by using a DDS to generate the BPSK at 12.8MHz and up-converting using a mixer to 409.6MHz, filtering, and amplifying to +10dBm.

Is this the best way to do this? I have also read that I can use a 32x PLL multiplier... would that be a better way?

Factors I am taking into consideration:

1. Complexity to design circuit/pcb
2. Cost of components
3. Low phase noise, low spurs, emi, etc.
4. Using a 12.8MHz ovenized oscillator (as 12.8 x 32 = 409.6)

Comment: What data rate are you wanting to run at?

Comment: 500 bits per second

Comment: According to Wikipedia, [BPSK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPSK) has two points at +90 and -90 (or equivalently +0 and +180) degrees. I am curious -- why would anyone want to use "-10 degrees and +10 degrees"? (Should this be a separate question?)

Comment: @davidcary To reduce the signal bandwidth.

Comment: My understanding is that transmitting at -10 and +10 degrees is mathematically identical to transmitting an unchanging pilot carrier at 0 degrees and simultaneously transmitting a normal BPSK signal at -90 and +90 degrees, where the amplitude of the BPSK signal is smaller than -- tan(10 degrees) of -- the amplitude of the pilot. [Phil Karn](http://www.ka9q.net/vmsk/) seems to say that doesn't reduce the *real* signal bandwidth -- the frequency spacing required to avoid interference -- although it may appear to have a narrower bandwidth on a spectrum analyzer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMSK

Comment: Good point. I think you are correct! For my application, I am using Narrow Band SBPSK (shaped bpsk). Does your analysis hold true when you shape the symbol phase?

Comment: Yes, if you have any kind of RF communication whatsoever, then you then add some fixed unchanging pilot carrier, it doesn't change the real signal bandwidth required -- even when the result appears to have a narrower bandwidth on a spectrum analyzer.

Comment: Shaped symbols require less bandwidth than square pulses. Like all known communication techniques, shaped symbols require more than the minimum bandwidth given by the [Shannon-Hartley Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon-Hartley_Theorem). Some types of shaped symbols have another advantage: [more energy-efficient amps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_amplifier) than the linear amps required for QAM. Shaped symbols are used in [minimum-shift keying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/minimum-shift_keying) and [shaped-offset QPSK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying#SOQPSK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to go about doing this is basically bypassing the DDS altogether and generating the baseband from a DSP and generating the symbols using a IQ Modulator. A VCO based PLL can be used to generate an LO for the modulator.

Additionally, the magnitude of the I & Q baseband voltages has the following relation:

```
Vq = -tan(10°) * Vi
Vq = -tan(-10°) * Vi
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A design worth considering is a colpitts oscillator with an ADF4111 PLL controlling centre frequency via a varactor diode (other PLLs I'm sure would work just fine). Here's a simple picture of one and I'd replace the transistor with a BFR92A transistor. R4 should be shorted out for decent ops at 400MHz. It's an FM modulator and works nicely. The FM can turn to PM by differentiating the data.

[image]

The varactor would be in series with about 22pF from the top of the inductor. The other end of the varactor would be ground and the dc control thru a 10k from the PLL. This pretty much describes a circuit I once designed. I added an extra transistor fed from the base - this was an emitter follower output to a filter and simple antenna. It only produced 0dBm from a 3.3V supply so you may need to run it from a bigger supply or add an amplifier.

You can feed the data (after differentiating and amplitude reduction) via a small capacitor to the varactor. The downside of this is that it needs a little care seting up and if you are not hyper-bothered about the exact phase shift then it should be ok.

A further note about the ADF4111 - it needs a small MCU to set up its registers and a xtal for a frequency reference.

Comment: this is an amazing circuit. How can I design other circuits like this? Is there a specific book you can recommend?

Comment: @hassan789 No specific book to recommend I'm afraid to say - but maybe someone else can recommend one. Maybe you should start another question on this basis. I'm sure there'll be some good answers